# Create a new google sheet with a unique filename on google form submit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Is there a way to create a new google sheet with a unique filename every time a google form is being submitted?

Scenario:
Client-1: fills up form, and submits form. Creates a new google sheet called response_01-14-22 8:57:0006.xlsx
Client-2: fills up form, and submits form. Creates a new google sheet called response_02-14-22 13:30:0000.xlsx
...

Comment: How is the difference between "Client-1" and "Client-2" known? Can I ask you about the logic for retrieving the filenames of `response_01-14-22 8:57:0006.xlsx` and `response_02-14-22 13:30:0000.xlsx`? And, can you provide your current script and the current issue of the script?

Comment: why create an excel file? could you also explain how to build the name?